# Is it slow to publish to no subscribers relative to one subscriber with ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq

### **Is it significantly slower to publish
when there is one subscriber v/s no subscribers at all?**

```
More Detail:
```

We're writing a **`ZeroMQ`** application, where speed is very important.
We have many nodes that communicate via **`REQ/REP`** as well as **`PUB/SUB`** and the network automatically selects **`{ ipc: | tcp: }`** transport-class, if the nodes are on the same machine.

We'd like to sometimes log the messages between certain nodes. With `PUB/SUB` this is easy, we just have a "logging node" subscribed to the publisher. However, with `REQ/REP`, we cannot read the request/response without becoming a proxy or otherwise slowing down the connection.

We're considering having all of the nodes using `REQ/REP` publish to a unique TCP address every time they send a message ( so each node has a "logging address" that they send all their messages to ), we'll then just subscribe to the "logging addresses" we're interested in, if we want to log.

```
Question:
```

Will we suffer a performance penalty if we ARE NOT subscribed to the "logging address"? A slowdown during logging is okay, but performance penalties during normal operation are not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How the subscription works?

Until **`v3.1`**, subscription mechanics ( a.k.a. a TOPIC-filter ) was handled on the **`SUB`**-side, so this part of the processign got distributed among all `SUB`-s ( at a cost of uniformly wide data-traffic across all transport-classes involved ) and there was no penalty, except for a sourcing such data-flow related workload ( ref. below ) on the **`PUB`**-side.

Since **`v3.1`**, the TOPIC-filter is processed on the **`PUB`**-side, at a cost of such a processing overhead, but saving all the previously wasted transport-capacities, consumed just to later realise at the `SUB`-side the message is not matching the TOPIC-filter and will be disposed off.

---

### Quantitative metric for what "significantly slower" indeed means in-vivo

As postulated in Question, the comparison ought be related to:
**`Scenario A:`** a `PUB`-process has no `SUB`-consumer connected/subscribed to any TOPIC-filter
**`Scenario B:`** a `PUB`-process has one `SUB`-consumer connected/subscribed to a TOPIC-filter

ZeroMQ has a state-full internal FSA, which saves both the programming architecture and resouces utilisation. This said, the `Scenario A` produces zero workload, i.e. has no impact related to `PUB`-processing, as there none such processing actually happens until a first real `SUB`-connects.

If your `Scenario B` does indeed represent the use-case, the additional processing overhead, related to serving just one single `SUB`-consumer, is easily measureable:

```
from zmq import Stopwatch as StopWATCH
aStopWATCH = StopWATCH()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------<TEST_SECTION>-start
aStopWATCH.start();s_PUB_send.send( "This is a MESSAGE measured for 0 SUB-s", zmq.NOBLOCK );t0 = aStopWATCH.stop()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------<TEST_SECTION>-end


# .connect the first SUB-process and let it .setsockopt() for v3.1+ accordingly


# -----------------------------------------------------------------<TEST_SECTION>-start
aStopWATCH.start();s_PUB_send.send( "This is a MESSAGE measured for 1 SUB-s", zmq.NOBLOCK );t1 = aStopWATCH.stop()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------<TEST_SECTION>-end

print "\nZeroMQ has consumed {0:} [us] for PUB-side processing on [Scenario A]\nZeroMQ has consumed {1:} [us] for PUB-side processing on [Scenario B]".format( t0, t1 )
```

The same test might be re-used to measure such difference in case `.connect()`-ed ( FSA-knows about the live counterparty ), but subscribed to nothing ( `.setsockopt( "" )` ) `SUB`-consumer processing is to be validated, **irrespective of the actually used `{ pre-v3.1 | v3.1+ }-API`** ( just be carefull to handle different versions of API in distributed-systems, where one cannot enforce uniform API-versions for remote nodes, that are outside of one's control of the Configuration Management ).

---

### And if performance is already bleeding?

One may further fine tune performance attributes for performance already constrained projects.

For selected processing tasks, performance, that one may guess a-priori is not so tough here, one may segregate workload-streams' processing by mapping each one on disjunct sub-sets of the multiple created I/O-threads:

map `s_REQ_sock.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 0 );`
and  `s_PUB_send.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 1 );`
resp. `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, ... );`

```
set s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE, 32000 ); // protective ceiling
set s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE,   True );  // retain just the last msg
set s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER,     0 );     // avoid blocking
set s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_TOS,        anAppToS_NETWORK_PRIO_CODE );
```

Comment: So it sounds like I won't incur a performance penalty for always sending logging messages to a logging address because zeromq knows that there is no subscriber attached?

Comment: Roger that, Sir. Sending side **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine is saving our worries in this manner. No consumer **`.connect()`-ed** means no task to perform at all on the **`PUB`** side. Isn't that a lovely use of just-enough system analysis? With a **reverse `.bind() / .connect` one may even control this behaviour right from the `PUB`-side processing** - isn't that great for a production switch for an in-vivo self-diagnostics?

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense to me!